# Using GLightbox and React, why doesn't my onClick method work in the lightbox display?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I'm trying to get the onClick function attached to the `<button>` element in this script to trigger. The enclosing div is opened as a GLightbox (https://github.com/biati-digital/glightbox) inline object.

```js
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
const GlightboxComponent = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const lightbox = GLightbox({
            selector: '.glightbox-link',
        });
    }, []);
    return (
        <div>
            <a href="#lightbox-div" className="glightbox-link" data-type="inline" 
                data-gallery="my-gallery">open lightbox</a>
            <div id="lightbox-div" style={{display: 'none'}}>
                <button onClick={() => console.log('click')}>mybutton</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};
export default GlightboxComponent;
```

The lightbox works to the extent that the div opens but when I click the button nothing happens. I wasn't able to find any interfering css or javascript so I'm wondering if the problem is somehow based on conflicts between React and Glightbox. As a test I ran an equivalent piece of code as a static website.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="/assets/vendor/glightbox/css/glightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#lightbox-div" class="lightbox-link" data-type="inline"
      data-gallery="my-gallery">open lightbox</a></p>
  <div id="lightbox-div" style="display: none">
    <button onClick="console.log('click');">mybutton</button>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="/assets/vendor/glightbox/js/glightbox.js"></script>
<script>
const lightbox = GLightbox({
    selector: '.lightbox-link',
});
</script>
</html>
```

In this case the onClick event on the button *does* work (opening and viewing it as a lightbox). The script imports in my React code are exactly the same, and using the same files (and are the only explicit imports used). Any insight on the issue would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library copies your `#lightbox-div` and pastes it into own html markup.
So, in fact, react `onClick` remained in the `#lightbox-div`, which has `display: none`.
Note that react `onClick` and native `onclick` are different things.